# See live network throughput per process in a Linux shell

Tags: gratis, linux, network-monitor, command-line

I am looking for a free program that can display the live network throughput per process in the Linux shell. As far as I know:

- [ifconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig) only lists interfaces and doesn't display the live network throughput:

  ```
  eth0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0F:20:CF:8B:42
         inet addr:217.149.127.10  Bcast:217.149.127.63  Mask:255.255.255.192
         UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
         RX packets:2472694671 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:44641779 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
         RX bytes:1761467179 (1679.7 Mb)  TX bytes:2870928587 (2737.9 Mb)
         Interrupt:28
  ```
- slurm only lists interfaces:

  [image: slurm screenshot]
- bmon only lists interfaces:

  [image: bmon screenshot]
- tcptrack shows every connection:

  [image: tcptrack screenshot]
- iftop does not display throughput per process:

  [image: iftop screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

You can use [NetHogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/):

- free
- install with `sudo apt-get install -y nethogs`
- runs in the terminal
- display the live network throughput per PID:

  [image: NetHogs screenshot]

Note that for NFS/AFS traffic you [will see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/143849/16704) `?` as PID:

[image: NetHogs screenshot: listing NFS traffic under "?"]